# Combination takeWhile, skipWhile

Tags: list, f#

In F#, I find when I want to use `takeWhile`, I usually also want to use `skipWhile`, that is, take the list prefix that satisfies a predicate, and also remember the rest of the list for subsequent processing. I don't think there is a standard library function that does both, but I can write one easily enough.

My question is, what should this combination be called? It's obvious enough that there should be a standard name for it; what is it? Best I've thought of so far is `split`, which seems consistent with `splitAt`.

Comment: `split` sounds good to me, or how about `splitBy`? I take it that `List.partition` is of no help to you? It also splits a list into 2 halves based on a predicate, but does so across the whole list, not only up to the first non-matching element.

Comment: I'd also agree that `split` makes the most sense for functions that take a predicate, since it parallels the use of functions like `filter`, `find` and `exists`. But if you want to use "split + some preposition", I'd suggest `splitWith` rather than `splitBy`. The other functions that use "by" in their names (`maxBy`, `sortBy`, `averageBy`, etc.) expect a projection function as their first parameter, while the functions that use "with" (`compareWith`, `sortWith`, etc.) expect what I'd call a "helper" function (one that makes a decision). So "by" fits better than "with", but no suffix fits best.

Comment: is `SkipAndTake` too much?

Comment: or maybe `TakeAfter`?

Comment: One or two concrete examples of input and desired output would be worth a thousand words :)

Comment: can you post your function?  I am looking for an implementation of this in F# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56814073/what-is-the-equivalent-of-scalas-seq-span-in-f/56819122#56819122

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`span` is another name I've seen for this function.  For example, [in Haskell](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:span)

Answer (score 1):

This part of your question stood out to me (emphasis mine):

> take the list prefix that satisfies a predicate, and also remember the rest of the list **for subsequent processing**

I am guessing that you want to recurse with the rest of the list and then apply this splitting function again. This is what I have wanted to do a few times before. Initially, I wrote the function that I think you are describing but after giving it more thought I realised that there might be a more general way to think about it and avoid the recursion completely, which usually makes code simpler. This is the function I came up with.

```
module List =
    let groupAdjacentBy f xs =
        let mutable prevKey, i = None, 0
        xs
        |> List.groupBy (fun x ->
            let key = f x
            if prevKey <> Some key then
                i <- i + 1
                prevKey <- Some key
            (i, key))
        |> List.map (fun ((_, k), v) -> (k, v))

let even x = x % 2 = 0
List.groupAdjacentBy even [1; 3; 2; 5; 4; 6]
// [(false, [1; 3]); (true, [2]); (false, [5]); (true, [4; 6])]
```

I found this one easier to name and more useful. Maybe it works for your current problem. If you don't need the group keys then you can get rid of them by adding `|> List.map snd`.

As much as I usually avoid mutation, using it here allowed me to use `List.groupBy` and avoid writing more code.

Answer (score 0):

`.slice` could capture the intent of a contiguous range:

```
List.slice skipPredicate takePredicate
```