# What is the equivalent of Scala's Seq.Span in F#?

Tags: .net, scala, f#

To quote [Scala's documentation](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/Seq.html#span(p:A=%3EBoolean):(C,C)):

```
def span(p: (A) => Boolean): (Seq[A], Seq[A])
```

Splits this iterable collection into a prefix/suffix pair according to a predicate.

Note: c span p is equivalent to (but possibly more efficient than) (c takeWhile p, c dropWhile p), provided the evaluation of the predicate p does not cause any side-effects.

Note: might return different results for different runs, unless the underlying collection type is ordered.

- p - the test predicate
- returns - a pair consisting of the longest prefix of this iterable collection whose elements all satisfy p, and the rest of this iterable collection.
- Definition Classes - IterableOps → IterableOnceOps
- Note - Reuse: After calling this method, one should discard the iterator it was called on, and use only the iterators that were returned. Using the old iterator is undefined, subject to change, and may result in changes to the new iterators as well.

---

When looking at the [F# documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/collections.seq-module-%5Bfsharp%5D) for Seq I don't see any equivalent.

groupBy, partition, splitAt, none of them match what I'm trying to do.  It's like doing a takeWhile and skipWhile at the same time but instead of needing two iterations you only need one where the function would return a tuple of (takeWhile, skipWhile).

The output should match the following function

```
module List
let span (predicate: 'a -> bool) (list: 'a list): ('a list * 'a list) =
    (list |> List.takeWhile predicate, list |> List.skipWhile predicate)
```

But only need one iteration since my sequence may be infinite.

```
[1;2;3;4] |> List.span (fun i -> i % 2 = 1) => ([1], [2;3;4])
```

Comment: This span function in the FSharpx.Collections library appears to be the equivalent for a list: https://github.com/fsprojects/FSharpx.Collections/blob/master/src/FSharpx.Collections/Collections.fs#L366-L374

Note that their implementation for a sequence just uses takeWhile and skipWhile as in your example for a list: https://github.com/fsprojects/FSharpx.Collections/blob/master/src/FSharpx.Collections/Collections.fs#L69-69

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I've come up with, it's not a great answer because it requires you eagerly iterate through the first one so if you return true long enough you will blow without of memory.  I will leave the question open for a few more days and if I don't see a better answer I will mark this one.  Again I would really like a better answer that completely works with an infinite sequence in any situation.

```
module Seq

let span (predicate: 'a -> bool) (sequence: 'a seq): ('a seq * 'a seq) =
    let enumerator = sequence.GetEnumerator()
    let isNotDone = ref (enumerator.MoveNext())
    let first = seq {
        let e = enumerator
        if !isNotDone then
            while (!isNotDone && predicate e.Current) do
                yield enumerator.Current
                isNotDone := e.MoveNext() }
    let second = seq {
        use e = enumerator
        if !isNotDone then
            yield e.Current
            while e.MoveNext() do
                yield e.Current }
    let eagerFirst = List.toSeq (Seq.toList first)
    (eagerFirst, second)
```

Answer (score 4):

Your explanation is not what `Seq.span` does in Scala: it partitions one sequence in two, putting all input elements into first tuple value as long as predicate function returns true. Once function returns false, all remaining elements will be pushed into second tuple value.

Example in F# would be like:

```ml
[1;2;3;4] |> Seq.span (fun i -> i % 2 = 1) => ([1], [2;3;4])
```

This can be achieved quite easily using mutualy recursive functions:

```ml
module Seq

open System.Collections.Generic

let span (predicate: 'a -> bool) (seq: 'a seq): ('a seq * 'a seq) =
    let rec insertLeft predicate (e: IEnumerator<'a>) (left: ResizeArray<'a>) (right: ResizeArray<'a>) =
        if e.MoveNext() then
            if predicate e.Current then
                left.Add e.Current
                insertLeft predicate e left right
            else
                // once predicate returned false, all consecutive elements land in right list
                right.Add e.Current 
                insertRight e right
    and insertRight (e: IEnumerator<'a>) (right: ResizeArray<'a>) =
        if e.MoveNext() then 
            right.Add e.Current
            insertRight e right
    let left = ResizeArray<_>()
    let right = ResizeArray<_>()
    use enumerator = seq.GetEnumerator()
    insertLeft predicate enumerator left right
    (upcast left, upcast right)
```

Comment: It does not appear your solution work with infinite sequences because of the ResizeArrays you are building, they will eventually blow out memory.

Comment: Also I've added additional information to my post to explain how (takeWhile, skipWhile) will give the exact same results scan but it needs two passes to work instead of one.

Comment: Yes, my implementation materializes the sequence instead of evaluating it lazily. I should have precise that. I traded off laziness for single-iteration and side-effect safety ( *imagine if one of the operations prior this one was about database call* ). Unfortunatelly it seems to be impossible to have them together (?) with lazy nature of sequences.

Comment: You are buffering both the left and the right, I think there would be a solution that would only buffer the left (takWhile) and lazy the (skipWhile), I would not prefer this but it's better than buffering them both and could also only be iterated once.

Answer (score 2):

I have a helper function which I find quite useful for this sort of thing:

```
module Seq =
    let groupAdjacentBy f xs =
        let mutable prevKey, i = None, 0
        xs
        |> Seq.groupBy (fun x ->
            let key = f x
            if prevKey <> Some key then
                i <- i + 1
                prevKey <- Some key
            (i, key))
        |> Seq.map (fun ((_, k), v) -> (k, v))
```

Note that it uses locally contained mutation in the implementation because it's the simplest way to reuse the existing `Seq.groupBy`.

This is actually a grouping function but it only puts items in the same group if they are adjacent to each other. To my mind this is a very general way of solving problems that need several uses of `takeWhile` and `skipWhile`, but simpler because it's all done in one pass. The grouping function returns a group key of any type rather than just a boolean, adding more flexibility.

Here's an example usage with a grouping function that returns a boolean:

```
[ 1; 2; -1; -2; 3; 4; -5 ]
|> Seq.groupAdjacentBy (fun x -> x > 0) // positive?
|> Seq.map snd
// seq [seq [1; 2]; seq [-1; -2]; seq [3; 4]; seq [-5]]
```

In this example the first two lines return the groups with their keys (`true`, `false`, `true`, `false` respectively). You can then use these keys in your logic, but if you don't care about them then the `Seq.map snd` will discard them. And you're left with a `seq<seq<int>>` as shown above.

Comment: Maybe I'm just too dense but I don't see how to implement scan using this function.  I've added additional information to my post to further explain scan.

Comment: I did understand what you meant but intentionally offered something different from span. In my experience something like span is often used recursively. This function gives the option of working at a higher level producing a collection with each step, which for me us usually easier to understand. This might be useful to you depending on exactly what you're trying to solve with span.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want something like the following, you'd just pass the same `Seq` (or `List` or whatever) to `filter` twice as follows:

```
//Returns a tuple of seq<'a> * seq<'a> (which looks like what you want).
let scalaSpanTuple test sq = (Seq.filter test sq, Seq.filter (test>>not) sq)
```

or:

```
//Returns a list of 2 lists of 'a
let scalaSpanList test ls = [List.filter test ls; List.filter (test>>not) ls]
```

etc.

Comment: This is not what I am looking for, this seems more like partition but takes multiple iterations, also I am not the one who downvoted you.